# The tcp client can not receive data from eventmachine

Tags: ruby, tcp, eventmachine

there is the code, the client:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'benchmark'
require 'socket'

i=0
TCPSocket.open "127.0.0.1", 8080 do |s|
  s.send "#{i}th sending", 0        
   if line = s.gets
     puts line
   end
end
```

the server:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'benchmark'
require 'eventmachine'
class Handler  < EventMachine::Connection
  def receive_data(data)
    sleep 2 # simulate a long running request
    send_data "send_response"
    puts data
  end
end

EventMachine::run {
  EventMachine::start_server("0.0.0.0", 8080, Handler)
  puts "Listening..."
}
```

The client can not print anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interaction between `s.gets` in the client and `send_data "send_response"` in the server.

Your small test works fine for me when I change:

```
send_data "send_response"
```

to

```
send_data "send_response\n"
```

The `s.gets` is waiting for a newline from the remote client. None comes.